# How to use different value in list and menu in vuetify v-select?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

How can I change [this](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/selects#customized-item-text-and-value) example so that in the menu I will get things like "Florida, FL" but in the actual v-select I get "FL" only.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      select: [{ state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' }],
      items: [
        { state: 'Florida', abbr: 'FL' },
        { state: 'Georgia', abbr: 'GA' },
        { state: 'Nebraska', abbr: 'NE' },
        { state: 'California', abbr: 'CA' },
        { state: 'New York', abbr: 'NY' },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-subheader>Custom items</v-subheader>
        </v-col>
  
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-select
            v-model="select"
            :items="items"
            item-text="state"
            item-value="abbr"
            label="Select"
            persistent-hint
            multiple
          ></v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Comment: Don't `return-object`. By default, `item-value` is returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change the settings, only add `@change` handler to the component, and handle it with a **method**. Watch for passing the emitted event to your method (**$event**). By passing the values of the emitted event to your method, you can work with the object that was selected (the event actually passes that object to your method).

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data() {
    return {
      select: [{
        menuText: 'Florida, FL',
        state: 'Florida',
        abbr: 'FL'
      }],
      items: [{
          state: 'Florida',
          abbr: 'FL'
        },
        {
          state: 'Georgia',
          abbr: 'GA'
        },
        {
          state: 'Nebraska',
          abbr: 'NE'
        },
        {
          state: 'California',
          abbr: 'CA'
        },
        {
          state: 'New York',
          abbr: 'NY'
        },
      ],
    }
  },
  computed: {
    menuItems() {
      return this.items.map(e => {
        return {
          menuText: e.state + ', ' + e.abbr,
          ...e
        }
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    logValue(e) {
      this.select = e
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
/*.v-select__selection.v-select__selection--comma {
  display: none;
}*/

.v-text-field__prefix {
  color: #242729;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@mdi/font@4.x/css/materialdesignicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify@2.x/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-container fluid>
      <v-row align="center">
        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-subheader>Custom items</v-subheader>
        </v-col>

        <v-col cols="6">
          <v-select v-model="select" :hint="`${select.state}, ${select.abbr}`" :items="menuItems" item-text="abbr" item-value="menuText" return-object single-line @change="logValue($event)" multiple>
            <template v-slot:item="{ item }">
              <strong>{{item.menuText}}</strong>
            </template>
          </v-select>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

#### OTHER HINT

You had an extre Vue script reference in your snippet - I removed it in mine.

## EDIT

To have access to the dropdown items, you have to use the **item slot** v**v-select** offers. There you can modify the appearance of the items however you want.

Comment: When I select something it shows the long name instead of short name in the text-field I want to show the short name in the text field and both names in the menu. also I want multiple selection(sorry, I forgot to edit the example code to be multiple)

Comment: I modified the snippet to use a **computed** value instead of the **data** directly - this way you can alter the objects that the **v-select** component uses and returns. You can display or process the **select** data value as you need.

Comment: Except for the part under "EDIT", this answer seems totally unrelated to the question.